# django rest framework - Nested serialization not including nested object fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i'm trying to get nested object fields populated, however the only thing being returned is the primary key of each object (output below):

```
{
    "name": "3037",
    "description": "this is our first test product",
    "components": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
```

How do I have the component model's fields populated as well (and not just the PKs)? I would like to have the name and description included.

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Bag name', max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField ('Description of bag',  max_length=512, blank=True)
    urlKey = models.SlugField('URL Key', unique=True, max_length=64)  
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Component(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Component name', max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField('Component of product',  max_length=512, blank=True)
    fits = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='components')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fits.name + "-" + self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from app.models import Product, Component, Finish, Variant

class componentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
    model = Component
    fields = ('name', 'description', 'fits')

class productSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #components_that_fit = componentSerializer(many=True) 
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'components')
        #fields = ('name', 'description', 'components_that_fit' )
```

The [documented approach](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations) doesn't seem to be working for me, and gives me the following error (you can see the lines following the standard approach commented out in the serializers.py entry above:

`Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'components_that_fit' on serializer 'productSerializer'.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 'Product' instance.
Original exception text was: 'Product' object has no attribute 'components_that_fit'.`

**Update based on answer**

Thanks to @Carlton's answer below, here's what is working for me:
*serializers.py* was changed and now looks like this:

```
class productSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    components = componentSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'components')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling the field `components_that_fit`, you're having the serialiser look for an attribute by that name. (There isn't one, hence your error.)

Two ways to fix it:

- Call the field `components`, but declare it as `components = componentSerializer(many=True)`
- Set `source='components'` [field option](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) when declaring the `components_that_fit` field.

The reason you get primary keys is that, unless declared explicitly, [relations default to `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield).

I hope that helps.

Comment: wooot, that was quick :)

Comment: thanks @Carlton - option 1 fixed it for me. I've updated the question with the resulting output based on your answer :)